# Flutter Widget Navigator Failed

Tags: flutter, macos

I have a file called My Drawer which the user can access by tapping on the top left menu icon. The drawer holds the logout button and an about button for now. The code has zero error and the about button works perfectly but when I press on the logout button, the app shows me a blank screen and when I hot reload the app I get the follwing error.

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5501 pos 12: '_history.isNotEmpty': is not true. See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/ testing/errors
```

How do fix this error?

MyDrawer code:

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyDrawer> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {


  // method to log user out
  void logUserOut(BuildContext context) {
    // pop drawer
    Navigator.pop(context);
    // pop app
    Navigator.pop(context);
    // go back to login page
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>  const HandleLogout(),
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Drawer header
          const DrawerHeader(
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.phone_iphone_rounded,
                size: 64,
              ),
            ),
          ),

          const SizedBox(height: 25),

          // ABOUT PAGE
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const AboutPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.info),
                title: Text(
                  "A B O U T",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // LOGOUT BUTTON
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
            child: ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
              onTap: () => logUserOut(context),
              title: Text(
                "L O G O U T",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

The HandleLogout is another file that uses FirebaseAuth SignOut to signout from the app.

Comment: I have a feeling that it has to do with calling `navigator.pop` twice in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your route stack. You can use `pushReplacement`.

```dart
 // method to log user out
  void logUserOut(BuildContext context) {
    // pop drawer
    Navigator.pop(context);

    // go back to login page
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>  const HandleLogout(),
      )
    );
  }
```